# how to revert TILL specific commit in git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset, git-revert

> i want to revert **TILL** **specific** commit in **git**

i have done 3 commits in git

- 1st commit  > 1:am
- 2nd commit  > 2:am
- 3rd commit  > 3:am

now i want to **revert** directly to this **specific** 1st commit !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to completely remove the unwanted commits from the history:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^^^
```

However if you want to preserve the history, you should use `git-revert`:

```
$ git revert <sha1-of-3rd-commit> <sha1-of-2nd-commit>
```

This will  apply new commits that revert the old ones.